# WSO2 ESB can not response json message

Tags: json, wso2, wso2-esb

I have a service response is :

```
<Response>
    <BackUrl>www.hao123.com</url>
    <resultCode>0</resultCode>
</Response>
```

I set `messageType:"application/json"`. The response is:

```
{Response:{"BackUrl":"coship.com","resultCode":"0";}}.
```

But I need transform this message to a json string like:

```
{"BackUrl":"http://www.coship.com","resultCode":"0"}
```

How ro remove node "Response". I tried to use script `mc.setPayloadJSON` in ESB 4.5.1. But errors happened.

```
https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-1618?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel#issue-tabs
```

Anyone can help me? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue reported as mentioned, and it is not resolved yet. But, you can set messgae type  as

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
```

and check?

here is a [post](http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2012/10/rest-support-in-wso2esb-handling-json.html) which may useful to you

Comment: Thank you Ratha, that's very kind of you. I set "application/json". And the response is:{Response:{"BackUrl":"http://www.coship.com","resultCode":"0"}}. How to remove the node "Response"?

Comment: Having an XSLT mediator and  arranging the message wothour response node wont work?